# C++ transferring comma sepetated floats from argument 3-column csv file into 3 sepetate vectors

Tags: c++, csv, vector, command-line-arguments, delimiter

I have a csv file which is passed from command line and looks something like:

```
    2.26645, -0.258901, -213.274
    5.45054, 345.333, 73.1871
    7.18079, 25.156, 125.408
    ...
```

I want to extract these floats into 3 float vectors, one for each column. I have only been able to extract ALL floats in just one vector,

```
ifstream input_file;
input_file.open(argv[1],ios::out);

string line;
string value;

while(getline(input_file,line)){
    istringstream ss(line);
    while(getline(ss,value,',')){


    }


}
```

The issue is that as stated before, I want 3 vectors one for each column instead.

Comment: Why three vectors? Why not a single structure wrapping the three numbers on each line, and a vector of those structures?

Comment: maybe eventually. I'm just wrapping my head around small parts of a progressively bigger program.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is because you put the *file name* into the string stream instead of the file contents. Open a proper [input file stream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) to read the data from the file.

---

After you solved the above problem, the second problem could be solved by reading one line at a time from the file and put into an [*input* string stream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream). Then parse the input from that stream.

That parsing can be done similarly to what you do know skipping over space and the comma. Or you can use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) three times to get each value (`std::getline` supports custom "field" separators) and then [convert the strings to floating point numbers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof). Put each number in its own vector.

Comment: I modified the code how will can i store the values of each columns now?